# Is there a limit on the current carrying capacity of a wire?

Tags: current, wire

Obviously, for continuous current there is - the melting point. If it is superconducting, the field strength at which it quenches. OTOH if we specify a pulse of arbitrarily short timescale in order to avoid melting we introduce high frequency components that create a skin effect, which in turn feeds back into any current limitation.

However - is there any other physical limit on the current carrying capacity? For example, at some point the field is going to liquify the metal due to sheer pressure. What else?

Comment: The melting point of the insulation.

Comment: Short pulses imply wide bandwidths, which imply the need for transmission lines.  At some point the conductors will spark over, or be physically deformed by the magnetic attraction and/or repulsion.  It's almost an academic question -- I suspect that any practical application that starts running into secondary or tertiary effects like this is going to have its own unique set of complications.

Comment: I have seen a demonstration where a capacitor was discharged into a short piece of wire vaporizing it.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a physics answer rather than an engineering answer. Maybe the Physics SE would be a better place for this question?

Comment: Electromigration. At sufficiently high current density the metal atoms will be physically moved, leading to conductor thinning and eventual failure.

Comment: @CharlesCowie May 1962 issue of Scientific American had a cover article on exploding wires.

Comment: Your high current pulse is going to be limited by the wire's inductance, as well.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany That article may have inspired the demonstration that I saw. The demo was part of a university engineering school open house that I attended in the spring of 1963.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be held to the quality standard of the question, but the first thing that springs to mind is the maximum power delivery of a wire.  I think the most power a wire can possibly deliver is at the point where voltage drop equals load voltage.  I seem to remember this is a mathematical proof rather than rule of thumb, but in many cases it would limit potential current to less than that which would destroy the wire.  There are also [places where it's OK to destroy the wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosively_pumped_flux_compression_generator).

Comment: You might be interested in the use of exploding wires to produce shockwaves. After the wire is vaporized, the plasma still conducts for a while. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploding_wire_method

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Also foil "slappers" that are used in place of traditional detonators, esp in modern nuclear weapons